# Underscore - get the same sume of the values objects from array

Tags: arrays, object, underscore.js, each

```
var array = [
    { T: 2, G: 2, K: 2},        //<--- return this cause T+G+K = 6
    { T: 2, G: 2, K: 3},
    { T: 1, G: 3, K: 2}         //<--- return this cause T+G+K = 6
];
```

I would like to return the same sum of the fields objects from array. How to do this?

I was trying like:

```
var array = [
    { T: 2, G: 2, K: 2 },        //<--- return this cause T+G+K = 6
    { T: 2, G: 2, K: 3 },
    { T: 1, G: 3, K: 2 }         //<--- return this cause T+G+K = 6
];  

//getting uniq array
var uniqArray = _.uniq(array, function(value) {
    return value.T + value.G + value.K;
}

//uniqArray = [
//  { T: 2, G: 2, K: 2 },
//  { T: 2, G: 2, K: 3 }
//];

//getting the difference between uniq and normal array
var differenceArray = _.difference(array, uniqArray);

//differenceArray = [
//  { T: 1, G: 3, K: 2 }
//];

//and finally try to get the same objects in array like:
var theSame = [];
_.each(array, function(value) {
    if((value.T + value.G + value.K) === _.each(differenceArray, function(num) {
    return num.T + num.G + num.K; }) {
        theSame.push(value);
    }
);
```

but i really don't know underscore well so I think that I'm trying to do something by using too much and making it too hard. How can I easily get these objects?

Thank you

Comment: First of all I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Lets begin with your comments. You commented a line: " { T: 2, G: 2, K: 2 }, //<--- return this cause T+G+K = 7" and as I can see T+G+K is equal to 6 in this case and then 7 (line without a comment) and the last line is commented with a sum equal to 6.

Comment: Ou, sorry for mistake. I edited earlier the values and forget about editing these comments. I need to return from the array all these objects which fields sum equals 6 (tha first and third one).

Answer (score 0):

If I properly understood you this should finally work.

```
var array = [
  { T: 2, G: 2, K: 2 },
  { T: 2, G: 2, K: 3 },
  { T: 1, G: 3, K: 2 }
];

var uniqArray = _.uniq(array, function(value) {
  return value.T + value.G + value.K;
});

var differenceArray = _.difference(array, uniqArray);

var sums = _.map(differenceArray, function(item) {
  return item.T + item.G + item.K;
});

var result = _.filter(array, function(item) {
  var sum = item.T + item.G + item.K; 
  return _.contains(sums, sum);
});
```

And cleaner version:

```
var arraySum = function(item) {
  return item.T + item.G + item.K;
};

var notUniqueSums = _.chain(array)
  .difference(_.uniq(array, arraySum))
  .map(arraySum)
  .value();

var result = _.filter(array, function(item) { 
  return _.contains(notUniqueSums, arraySum(item));
});
```